# Concatenate String with Variables

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Input dataset is like:

```
test = data.frame(Var_a = c("A|B","C|D|E","F"),Var_b = c("X"))
```

Desired output dataset is like:

```
test1 = data.frame(Var_C = c("AX|BX","CX|DX|EX","FX"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R option :

splitting the string on `|`, pasting each word with corresponding  `Var_b` value and collapsing the string back.

```
test$Var_c <- mapply(function(x, y) paste0(x, y, collapse = '|'), 
                 strsplit(test$Var_a, '|', fixed = TRUE), test$Var_b)

test

#  Var_a Var_b    Var_c
#1   A|B     X    AX|BX
#2 C|D|E     X CX|DX|EX
#3     F     X       FX
```

Answer (score 1):

you can separate the item to have one per row using the convenient `separate_rows()` from the {tidyverse}, after adding the id for the last paste.

Something like

```r
library(tidyverse)
test <- data.frame(Var_a = c("A|B","C|D|E","F"),Var_b = c("X"))
test %>% 
  mutate(id = seq_len(nrow(test))) %>% 
  separate_rows(Var_a) %>% 
  mutate(Var_c = paste0(Var_a, Var_b)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(Var_c = paste0(Var_c, collapse = "|"))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      id Var_c   
#>   <int> <chr>   
#> 1     1 AX|BX   
#> 2     2 CX|DX|EX
#> 3     3 FX
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use gsub and lookahead regular express:

```
test%>%mutate(Var_C=gsub('(\\w)(?=\\||$)',paste0('\\1',Var_b),Var_a, perl=TRUE))

#  Var_a Var_b    Var_C
#1   A|B     X    AX|BX
#2 C|D|E     X CX|DX|EX
#3     F     X       FX
```